# Pandas plot dataframe by index, how it works?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

Given the data:

```
Column1; Column2; Column3
1; 4; 6
2; 2; 6
3; 3; 8
4; 1; 1
5; 4; 2
```

With the following code I get the following graphic:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('test0.csv',delimiter='; ', engine='python')
df.plot(0,0)
plt.savefig('fig0.png')
```

[image]

And, with the following code I get the following graphic:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('test0.csv',delimiter='; ', engine='python')
df.plot(0,1)
plt.savefig('fig1.png')
```

[image]

What's the logic in `df.plot(m,n)`? Let's say I want to plot `Column2 X Column3`  what's `m` and `n`(`df.plot(2,3)`) ?

Comment: If you want to plot Column2 vs Column3, why don't you just do `df.plot(x="Column2", y="Column3")`?

Comment: Because I don't want to use names.

Comment: It's rather perverse to give your columns names and not use them, especially as the ability to use names is one of the main advantages of pandas.

Comment: I'll consider your comment (I'm sill learning this things). But I'm thinking in setting the index (`m` and `n`) programmatically, that's why I need access by index.

Comment: Note that you can access the column names programmatically as well (via `df.columns`), which is in fact what happens under the hood when you use numerical indexes.

Comment: Would you mind to discuss `df.columns` approach a little bit more?

Comment: unutbu edited his answer to show a simple example.  If you need more than than, you would need to explain more about what you're trying to do and why you think you need to use numerical positions.  Perhaps a separate question would be better for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever column is used as `x` is removed from the DataFrame before `y` is looked up.  (Or, more technically, `x` is set as the index, which means its no longer available as a column.)  So if you do `.plot(x=0, y=0)`, the `x=0` means "use the first positional column", and the `y=0` means "use whatever will be the first positional column after the x column is removed".

Needless to say this could get confusing, because whether `y` shifts in position depends on whether it was before or after `x`.  So if you do `.plot(x=3, y=1)`, then y really is column #1, but if you do `.plot(x=0, y=1)`, then y is actually column #2 (it becomes number 1 after column 0 is removed).

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `x` and `y` by ordinal position, you'll reach [this bit of code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L2449) when calling `df.plot(x, y)`:

```
    if isinstance(data, DataFrame):
        if x is not None:
            if com.is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():
                x = data.columns[x]
            data = data.set_index(x)
```

This converts `x` from an ordinal value (e.g. 0) to a column label name (e.g. `'Column1'`).
Notice that `data.set_index(x)` is called. So if `x` equals 0, the first column gets set as the index. Next, when `y` is similarly converted into a column label,
the 0th column is now `'Column2'`.  Hence, `df.plot(0,0)` plots Column2 versus Column1.

To plot Column3 versus Column2 you would therefore use `df.plot(1,1)`, since `data.columns[1]` is `'Column2'`, and then once it is set as the index, `data.columns[1]` is then `'Column3'`.

---

As [BrenBarn points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936983/pandas-plot-dataframe-by-index-how-it-works/39937159#comment67156153_39936983) in the comments, a much less error-prone way of specifying the columns is by label name. 
Or, if you really want to use ordinal values, pass them to `df.columns` explicitly:

```
df.plot(x=df.columns[x], y=df.columns[y])
```

Since `df.columns[x]` and `df.columns[y]` are column label names, their meaning is not affected by `set_index`, so there is less confusion.

Comment: To plot Column2 vs Column3 you would use `df.plot(2,1)` since that sets `x=df.columns[2]` which is `Column3`, and then after `Column3` is set as the index, `y=df.columns[1]` would (still) be `Column2`.

Comment: You mean `df.plot(x=df.columns[2], y=df.columns[1])`?

Comment: Yes, that would work, and it avoids the confusion caused by `set_index` when using ordinal indices.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), you can define *m* and *n* (*x* and *y* in the documentation) like this:

```
df.plot(df.columns[1],df.columns[2])
```

- 'm' should be -> `df.columns[1]` ,i.e., the column name of the position 1
- 'n' should be -> `df.columns[2]` ,i.e., the column name of the position 2

If you want to use the positions, would be:

```
df.plot(1,1)
```

The logic using position is: when we put *1* in the horizontal axis, this column is removed from the options for the vertical axis, so there is only two options available (with new indexes). Thats why `df.plot(0,0)` actually sets first and the next column as the data and `df.plot(1,1)` uses the second and last columns. I didn't found it in the documentation, I discovered it testing.

I think the idea is: makes no sense plot the same columns in axis x and y, so the first column given is not available for the other axis. I hope it help! =)

*PS:It will plot in a weird zoom and position, but if you zoom out and move through the plot you will confirm that the values matches with the data of each column*